# File.canWrite and Files.isWritable not giving correct value on Linux

Tags: java, file, file-permissions

I have this test java program

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class TestFileReadOnly
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String filePath = args[0];
        File f = new File(filePath);

        System.out.println("File.canWrite() for file: " + filePath + ", is: " + f.canWrite());
        System.out.println("Files.isWritable() for file: " + filePath + ", is: " + Files.isWritable(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(f.getParent(), f.getName())));
    }
}
```

I login on Linux using root and create two files.

```
echo "test file" > /root/ro.txt
echo "test file" > /root/rw.txt
chmod 444 /root/ro.txt
chmod 777 /root/rw.txt
```

When I execute the test program this way, the output is always incorrect

```
[root@xxx ~]# /jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java TestFileReadOnly /root/ro.txt
File.canWrite() for file: /root/ro.txt, is: true
Files.isWritable() for file: /root/ro.txt, is: true
[root@xxx ~]# /jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java TestFileReadOnly /root/rw.txt
File.canWrite() for file: /root/rw.txt, is: true
Files.isWritable() for file: /root/rw.txt, is: true
```

I am basically looking for java code to verify if the file is read only, but am not able to acheive it using above. However, this works well on Windows. I tried compiling and executing using jdk1.7.0_07, jdk1.7.0_75 and jdk1.8.0_31 but the result is same. Any help to address this is highly appreciated.

**Solution:**
Used @Matteo 's suggestion to use PosixFileAttributes for UNIX-like platforms. The working code is given below:

```
private boolean isFileReadOnly(File file)
{
    boolean isReadOnly = false;
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))
    {
        // All Windows versions
        isReadOnly = !file.canWrite();
    }
    else
    {
        // All Unix-like OSes.
        Path path = Paths.get(file.getParent(), file.getName());
        PosixFileAttributes attributes = null;
        try
        {
            attributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, PosixFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e)
        {
            // File presence is guaranteed. Ignore
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (attributes != null)
        {
            // A file is read-only in Linux only when it has 0444 permissions.
            Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = attributes.permissions();

            if (!permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE)
                && !permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE)
                && !permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE)
                && !permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE)
                && !permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE)
                && !permissions.contains(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE))
            {
                isReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isReadOnly;
}
```

Comment: Does whichever user you are running java as have access to view those folders? If they can't access those folders, I don't think they can access the files.

Comment: You can't access `/root` unless you are `root` normally.

Comment: put the files in your home-folder `~/anysubfolder` and try again

Comment: I am login and executing as root on Red Hat Linux 6.4 on x86_64 platform. Can someone try it on their system if it works?

Comment: I am sorry for incorrect output posted above. The correct output is updated above

Comment: I believe that root can by-pass UNIX permissions and write to read-only file. You should run your java program as normal user.

Comment: To follow-up on @vsb: I know you did the `chmod` and everything, but have you *actually* tested to see if you can write the "read-only" file?

Comment: My application is going to execute as root, so running as non-root is not an option. I can open the file in vi and cannot save using ":w" but can save using ":w!". The important question is, isn't there any way in Java that can return result based on permissions set on the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing your program as a normal user you will get `false` in both cases as you are not able the `/root` directory.

Executing your program as `root` you will get `true` in both cases as `root` can write a file even without the write permission:

```
$ echo uuu > ro.txt 
$ echo > ro.txt 
$ ls -l ro.txt 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1 Feb  6 15:03 ro.txt
$ cat ro.txt 

$ echo Test > ro.txt 
$ cat ro.txt 
Test
```

Comment: I just tested on my machine as root and works as expected. Could you please post the result of `ls -ld /root/`

Comment: [root@xxx ~]# ls -ld /root/
dr-xr-x---. 33 root root 4096 Feb  6 18:57 /root/

Comment: Isn't there any way in Java that can return result based only on permissions set on the file without considering effective capability based on owner and login user? Is there some other API with which this can be achieved?

Comment: You could use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html but it only works on POSIX systems

Comment: As File.canWrite() was working on Windows, I used the PosixFileAttributes approach for UNIX-like platforms (my desired platforms - AIX, HP-UX and Solaris are all fully POSIX compliant). The method that worked is given below:

Comment: As I could not paste the working code, I have modified the question and have posted the working solution above.